# Firebase content not loading on ios 10 - ionic app

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, firebase, content-security-policy

Currently working on a Ionic app. Content from Firebase stop loading on iOS 10. On android still working fine. I'm using AngularFire 1.2.0 and Firebase 2.4.2. I've been looking for the new Content Security Policy because I'm getting this error repeatedly

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made. (.lp, line 0)
```

So I added in my `index.html` the corresponding meta tag but still not working.  The connection with another app on Heroku works fine. Don't know what I'm missing.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src 'self' gap://ready file://* *;
       script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
         127.0.0.1:*
         https://*.herokuapp.com/
         https://*.firebaseio.com/;
       style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'
         127.0.0.1
         https://*.herokuapp.com/
         https://*.firebaseio.com/;
        connect-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
         127.0.0.1:*
         https://*.herokuapp.com/
         https://*.firebaseio.com/">
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just had to add "wss://.firebaseio.com" and "https://.firebase.com/" to my CSP connect-src rules.